# Cannot start TJWS

Tags: java, servlets, tjws

I have understand that TJWS is simple to embed but I have no luck with this code

```
public class Test {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

        final Serve serve = new Serve();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                serve.serve();
            }
        }).start();
    }
}

[Thu Jan 10 17:59:38 CET 2013] Unhandled exception: java.lang.NullPointerException, server is terminating.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Acme.Serve.Serve.serve(Serve.java:720)
    at Test.main(Test.java:17)
```

Java7/TJWS 2.3.2 Final

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the Serve source code ? Line 720 looks like:

```
   Socket socket = acceptor.accept();
```

and I suspect you need to call `init()` prior to `serve()`

Comment: Didn't see that init(). Thanks.